# How do I find out why my iPad 1 Safari crashes?

Tags: mobile-safari

I'm developing a html5/javascript site and there is a page that occasionally crashes Safari on iPad 1.

Is there a crash log or something similar so I can see what it is that is causing Safari to crash?

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Mac and have Xcode installed, you can hook said device up to your computer and choose to use it for development (note you don't need to be a registered iOS developer). After that you should be able to see the device in the organiser (hit ⇧⌘2 to show the organiser) and inspect its logs, simply find the log pertaining to Safari and you should be able to figure out what's causing the crash.

Comment: I don't understand how you can use the crash logs to determine what part of your code is causing the crash. The crash logs will tell you what Safari did to cause the crash, but it doesn't seem to tell you which line of JS (or CSS or HTML) caused the crash.

Answer (score 2):

In the settings for Safari, you can turn on a Debug Console that will show Javascript and similar errors as they appear.  Unfortunately, you can't inspect elements or do any thorough debugging with the Debug Console, it just lists the errors.

In IOS 5, you'll have to go into the Advanced Safari settings to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the data at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/crash/ and http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/retrieving-crash-reports-on-ios

After syncing with iTunes find the crash logs at `CrashReporter/MobileDevice/[Your_Device_Name]`

From the device hit up `General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & Usage Data` , but note there may be no way to sort this list by time, so it gets kinda random.